# Is there a way to use layer shadows and view transitions together?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, layer, uiviewanimation

I'm using a view transition (UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft) to change between 2 views of a parent view. First I tried setting a shadow on the parent (view.layer's shadow), but the shadow disappears during the animation and comes back after. I also tried putting individual shadows on the 2 child views, and same thing happens.

Short of saving the shadow as a separate image, what can I do to animate between views with the shadow still visible?

Thanks.

Edit: So it seems like the view's maskToBounds is set to YES during transition (I tried adding a shadow UIImage and it still got cropped). Any way to turn that off? I assume it's an optimization.

Edit: For what I need (shadow views are in a scrollview), dynamic shadows lag badly. So I used .png shadows and they don't lag anymore. For preventing cutoff, I put my view inside another view so that my shadows are actually within the parent view bounds, and they flip perfectly.